# How to include a view in another view in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have an add.ctp file, which will enable the user to add new entries,
there is another view.ctp file which will list all the existing
entries from the database.
How would I include these existing entries within the add view page,
So that user should be able to view the existing entries at the bottom
of the page when he is making a new entry from add page?

Thanking you

Answer (score 5):

You could extract the view code you want to use in both views into an [element](http://book.cakephp.org/view/97/Elements).

Answer (score 1):

or load the view underneath through an ajax call when an entry is clicked.